# Client Side Moxi case?

Tags: couchbase

I was wondering if I could see any example source code (Language: C) of a client that uses client-side Moxi.

I've seen architecture , but I have no idea how to write it in codes.

Also, from the get_callback function, if I need to return the CAS value and the Data received, is there any suggested way to do this?

And what is this vbucketmap thing? what do they represent and how to configure them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Client side moxi means that you setup a moxi server on your client machine and then just tells the client to connect to moxi on your local host. This means that if moxi is running on localhost port 11211 then you tell you client to connect to localhost port 11211 and moxi will handle communication with the server. You don't need to write any special code to do this.

> > Also, from the get_callback function, if I need to return the CAS value and the Data received, is there any suggested way to do this?

I'm not very familiar with the c api, but there is probably a gets function call that returns the cas id in the callback.

> > And what is this vbucketmap thing? what do they represent and how to configure them?

A vbucket map is a map of servers to VBuckets. In Couchbase Server there are 1024 vbuckets that your data can hash into. VBuckets a spread around a cluster and the map tells the client which server to send a request to. With that said you shouldn't ever touch the vbucket map with your code. The map is obtained from the cluster and managed by either the client-side SDK or in your case Moxi.

Comment: so hard to install Moxi on my CentOS... keep getting memcached related error (not found) ... making me installl various memcache library... keep giving me stupid error...

Comment: Just download the rpm. http://packages.couchbase.com/releases/1.8.0/moxi-server_x86_64_1.8.0.rpm

Then type "rpm -i package_name". Also, this link is for the 64 bit rpm.

Comment: Installation was successful 
I've put Host as "serverIP:11211" and tried running it.  I get "vbucket stream socket is closed!" whats wrong with it?

Comment: The streaming port is 8091. Also whenever I setup moxi on a client machine I just go to my server that has Couchbase installed and type 'ps -ef' to see a list of all running process and look for the moxi process. Copy the command for how moxi was started to the place you want moxi to run and then just replace the appropriate values in the command. Let me know if you run into any issues.

Comment: I am keep typing moxi-server start and it says started but if I type moxi-server status, moxi server is not running. I don't know why this is happening